# why won't these matrices broadcast together? ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (2,1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to setup back propagation for my neural network using numpy, but for some reason when I'm setting up the gradient decent equation for the matrix that holds my output weights, two of the matrix's (2,5)(5,1) in the gradient decent equation are not broadcasting together. Am I doing this wrong?

I've tried to dissect the equation into different parts to see if there is anything else that might be causing this, but so far I've pin pointed it down to specifically the entire matrix in the numerator, and the entire matrix in the denominator (the gradient decent equation is a fraction). I've also thought that it might be happening between the original output weights and the gradient decent equation, but that is also false because the the matrix for the output weights are (5,2) not (2,5). I've also tried functions other than numpy.divide, like using numpy.dot to multiply the first equation by the second to the power of -1.

## dissected code

```
self.outputWeights = self.outputWeights - l * 

#numarator
( -numpy.divide((2 * (numpy.dot(y.reshape(self.outputs, 1), (1+numpy.power(e, -n-b))).reshape(self.neurons, self.outputs)-w)).reshape(self.outputs, self.neurons), 

#denominator
(numpy.power(1+ numpy.power(e, -n-b), 2)).reshape(self.neurons, 1)))
```

## actual code

```
n = self.HIDDEN[self.layers]
b = self.bias[self.layers]
w = self.outputWeights

self.outputWeights = self.outputWeights - l * ( -numpy.divide((2 * (numpy.dot(y.reshape(self.outputs, 1), (1+numpy.power(e, -n-b))).reshape(self.neurons, self.outputs)-w)).reshape(self.outputs, self.neurons), (numpy.power(1+ numpy.power(e, -n-b), 2)).reshape(self.neurons, 1)))
```

I expected that because of the fact that the columns of the first matrix and the rows of the second matrix are the same size, that it wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: You are, at some point, multiplying two matrices with the `*` operator. Either use `@` operator, or use `np.dot`. Make sure to do that *for all matrix multiplications*

Comment: What are you trying to do with `np.divide`?

Answer (score 0):

With a matrix product, `dot`, the rule is `last dim of A pairs with 2nd to the last dim of B`:

```
In [136]: x=np.arange(10).reshape(5,2); y=np.arange(2)[:,None]                       
In [137]: x.shape, y.shape                                                           
Out[137]: ((5, 2), (2, 1))
In [138]: x.dot(y)                                                                   
Out[138]: 
array([[1],
       [3],
       [5],
       [7],
       [9]])
In [139]: _.shape                                                                    
Out[139]: (5, 1)
```

The `inner` 2's match, and the result is (5,1).

But with elementwise operations, such as `*` (multiply), divide and sum, those dimensions don't work

```
In [140]: x*y                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (2,1)
```

A transpose of `y` works:

```
In [141]: x*y.T                                                                      
Out[141]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 5],
       [0, 7],
       [0, 9]])
```

That's because `y.T` has shape (1,2). By broadcasting rules that can pair with (5,2) to produce a (5,2) array.  The size 1 dimension can be expanded to match the 5 of `x`.